# How to explicitely use inherited variables in Fortran?

Tags: variables, module, fortran

I have a question regarding best practices of model/variable usage:

Let's assume I have a module containing a few variable/parameter definitions and some subroutines that use these variables.

I do not need to explicitly use these variables in the subroutines since they are inherited from the parent module - but would it be better practice to do so?

Example:

```
module test
implicit none

integer, parameter :: a = 1
real               :: x

contains

subroutine idk(y,z)
  real, intent(in)  :: y
  real, intent(out) :: z

  if(a .eq. 1) then
    z = x*y + 5.
  else 
    z = x*y - 5.
  end if
end subroutine idk

end module test
```

The above example should work just fine but would it be better to add

```
use test, only: a,x
```

to the declaration part of subroutine `idk`?

In my reasoning, there are two main points here:

1) Pro: Explicitly adding this line let's me easily see which variables are actually needed in the subroutine. 
In many cases, the module contains quite a number of variables but only a few are needed in each subroutine. So for reasons of better comprehensibility, it would be beneficial to add this line.

BUT

2) Contra: In quite a few cases, one needs a lot of the variables/parameters declared above (sometimes numbering more than 100 parameters). Explicitly using these at the beginning of the subroutine just unnecessarily clutters the code, reducing the readability of the code.

Point 1 matters mostly if only a few variables need to be included, whereas point 2 is only important if many variables need to be included. But I think it would be silly to do one thing for few variables and another for many - once you have picked a convention, you should stick to it IMHO...

**Is there a best practice regarding this?**

Addition:
Alternatively, one could declare the subroutine as

```
subroutine idk(b,w,y,z)
```

and then call it as `idk(a,x,y,z)`.

On the one hand, this would give me greater flexibility if I later decide that I want to use `idk` with other variables.

On the other hand, it also increases the risk of mistakes if I change something later (say, I realize I don't need parameter `a` as a condition but parameter `c`. In the first cases, I simply switch out `a` -> `c` in the subroutine. But in the last case, I need to change every call to `idk(c,...)`. If there are a lot of these calls, this is prone to mistakes)

I would really appreciate your input! Thank you!

Comment: BTW see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141747/i-say-thank-you-and-it-gets-edited-out

Comment: another alternative would be to put the parameters in a separate module.

Comment: I always approach host association with caution and document the hell out of it in the source code. Note that even if you decide to pass the necessary variables as args to an internal procedure the host variables can still be "accidentally" accessed/modified. I think this is worse than forgetting to pass variables to an external subroutine, because in that case you would see the error right away.

Comment: I thought about putting the parameters in a separate module. The problem I have with this: The code is large and I have MANY parameters. By putting the variable declaration together with the main routines that use them, it seems to be nicely organized. Outsourcing them basically doubles the number of modules (unless I put them all in a big control file,which could be rather confusing since it would be very big indeed), making it harder to find the things I need. But now I am quite worried that this messes things up for me. How can I be sure not to inadvertently modify host associated varibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to `use` the module currently being defined. It is illegal. It may happen to compile if the module was compiled before and the compiler can find the `.mod` file, but file, but other than that it is wrong.

You should expect error such as

```
    ifort -c assoc.f90
assoc.f90(10): error #6928: The module-name on a USE statement in a program unit cannot be the name of any encompassing scoping unit.   [TEST]
  use test
------^
```

The module subroutine gets the variables from the host module through *host association* and the `use` statement is for *use association*. These are two different things and should not be mixed.

If you want to avoid global variables, pass them as arguments. This is a general advice. What is best depends on each case and the programmer and cannot be answered generally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I never had compiler problems with gfortran because of this (even when no `.mod` file was present) so I simply assumed both was allowed.

I assume _host association_ supercedes _use association_? So if I `use some_mod, only: some_variable` in my module `test`, then I don't need to (and should not) do this in the contained subroutine `idk` again?

Comment: You *can* do this in the subroutine again, but you don't have to. Provided it refers to a different module.

Comment: Gfortran gives me `Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'test.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory`.

Comment: So I could put 

`module test` \
`use some_mod, only: some_variable` \
`...` \
`contains` \
`subroutine idk(y,z)` \
`use some_mod, only: some_variable` \
`...`

and this would be allowed? Isn't `some_variable` already _host associated_ with `idk` since it is now "included" in `test`?

Comment: Yes that would be allowed. I am not sure about the exact standard terminology, but it certainly is allowed. Once you use-associate the symbol in the subroutine, you shadow whatever definition it had in the host module.